# Error in annotate when trying to indicate the statistically significant difference in bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

my code looks like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Name, y = prop, fill = Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "", y = "EQTL / gene") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens",name = "Number of cis EQTL") + 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size = 0.1, color = "grey"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )

p+geom_path(x=c(1,1,2,2),y=c(0.85,0.86,0.86,0.85))+
  annotate("text",x=1.5,y=1.2,label="p = 2e-16")
```

what I am trying to do is just to put a horizontal line between the middle points of those two bars above which would be written: p = 2e-16

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
Error in annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 1.2, label = "p = 2e-16") : 
  unused arguments (x = 1.5, y = 1.2, label = "p = 2e-16")
```

[image]

```
df <- readr::read_table(' prop                          Name
1 0.85            All_Genes
2 1.00 Glucose_Response_Genes103')
```

SOLUTION:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Name, y = prop, fill = Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Proportion of eGenes") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens",name = "Number of cis EQTL", labels = c("3124345", "26846")) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.ticks = element_line())

p + ggplot2::annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 1.2, label = "p < 2e-16", size = 3.5) +  
  ggplot2::annotate("rect", xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 1.1, ymax =1.1, alpha=0.3,colour = "black")
```

As @Axeman pointed out the issues was with: ggplot2::annotate

Still I should like to know how to edit this code and get smaller and more elegant bars?

Comment: Curious. Does anything change if you replace `annotate` with `ggplot2::annotate`?

Comment: The downvote is mine because this question contains too much code and is not reproducible. I will happily remove the downvote when those issues would be addressed - please don't forget to ping me

Comment: Hi Axeman I did: +   ggplot2::annotate("text",x=1.5,y=1.2,label="p = 2e-16")
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): x, y  so it seems that there was the issue with the library. Also do you know what I can do about this error?

Comment: Hi Tjebo I did upload my data on the bottom of the post. Sorry I forgot that at the first place

Comment: As much as I respect @Axeman, in this case the problem was *still not* the `annotate` call. In your solution you have removed the `geom_path` call and this is likely the reason why this plot then works.

Comment: As for changing the width: you should see this in relation to the final plot output (i.e., the dimensions of your jpg/tif/pdf or else. Once you have found appropriate dimensions of the plot, you can change the width using `geom_bar(width = ...)`

Comment: Hi Tjebo, geom_path solution with annotate also gave me error. I wrote that solution without geom_path because it's a bit easier to read for me personally although I upvoted your answer and I am thankful for that. Also thanks for the tip about width.

Comment: Exactly - it gave you the error *because* you had the `geom_path` call in it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the annotate call. It's your geom_path call which requires a data frame. I would probably annotate using `annotate(geom = 'segment')` rather than with `geom_path`, but here we go:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_path(data = data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2), y=c(0.85,0.86,0.86,0.85)), aes(x,y))+
  annotate("text",x=1.5,y=1.2,label="p = 2e-16")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The error message they posted does not appear to agree with your first sentence, I think.

Comment: @Axeman The error message does not fit to the problem indeed. A peculiarity. But the problem is the `geom_path` call

Comment: I think their `geom_path` call should work if they have 4 observations in their data.frame, otherwise they'd get an error about the wrong length of their aesthetics (although I agree using `annotate` would be better).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! the issue was with ggplot2::annotate. Do you by any chance know how to make these bars a bit smaller?

Comment: @anamaria no, the solution which you have provided also shows that the issue was not the `annotate`